# Why does an iPhone rename itself with (2)

Tags: ios

My son's find my iphone page, when I looked today after his phone number it has (2) - right after it. Yesterday it did not, and none of our other devices have that. Just wondering what that stands for?

Comment: did he recently get a new phone?

Comment: no it is the same one he has had over a year.  it has his name as usual but then after (2)

Answer (score 3):

That occurs when your Wifi network, or another Wifi network he's been connected to, think that there are two devices with the same name. It will then rename the device with a (2) or (3), etc. This is actually a bug in the software that Apple has used with the latest iteration of Yosemite and the Airport Extreme.

You can resolve this by shutting down your Airport Extreme, renaming your son's iPhone removing the (2), then turning the Airport Extreme back on.